# Speed correlation calculation - code too slow

Tags: python, performance, correlation

I'm trying to calculate speed correlation from a data file already existing which, works fine but is very slow.
The speed datafile contains about 1000 pts

```
def Correlation(data_vit,max_dt):
data_corre = pd.DataFrame(columns=['dt','Vx','Vy','Vxy'])
dfmean = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Vx','Vx','Vxy'])
data_corre_tmp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Vx','Vy','Vxy']) 
for dt in range(max_dt-1):  
    for t in range(max_dt-1-dt): # vx(t)vx(t+deltaT) + vy(t)vy(t+deltaT)
        Vx,Vy = data_vit.at[t+dt,'Vx']*data_vit.at[t,'Vx'] , data_vit.at[t+dt,'Vy']*data_vit.at[t,'Vy']

        data_corre_tmp = data_corre_tmp.append({     'Vx':  Vx ,
                                                     'Vy':  Vy ,
                                                     'Vxy': Vx+Vy
                                                    }, ignore_index=True)
    #moyenner sur tous les t possibles pour un deltaT

    dmean = {'dt':  [dt],
             'Vx':  [sum(data_corre_tmp['Vx'])/len(data_corre_tmp['Vx'])] ,
             'Vy':  [sum(data_corre_tmp['Vy'])/len(data_corre_tmp['Vy'])] ,
             'Vxy': [sum(data_corre_tmp['Vxy'])/len(data_corre_tmp['Vxy'])] 
             }

    dfmean = pd.DataFrame(data=dmean)
    data_corre = data_corre.append(dfmean, ignore_index=True)
    data_corre_tmp = data_corre.iloc[0:0]

    time.sleep(0.1)
    printProgressBar(dt + 1, max_dt, prefix = 'Progress:', length = 50)

return(data_corre)
```

I know it's pretty rough, I don't have much experience so I went for the "simple route"
Did I do anything that could take a lot of computing power for no reason? 
Because beside calculation Vx,Vy, I'm really just appending stuff

Answer (score 1):

This approach is very inefficient because:

- `data_corre_tmp.append` create a new dataframe and copy all the elements
- dataframe indexing is slow
- CPython loops are usually quite slow

Thus, you can speed-up the computation by multiple orders of magnitude by just appending data into lists (and not dataframe) and using numpy vectorized operations.

Here is an improved implementation:

```py
import numpy as np

def Correlation_v2(data_vit, max_dt):
    data_corre = pd.DataFrame(columns=['dt','Vx','Vy','Vxy'])
    dfmean = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Vx','Vx','Vxy'])
    allVx = np.array(data_vit['Vx'])
    allVy = np.array(data_vit['Vy'])
    data_corre = {'dt': list(range(max_dt-1)), 'Vx': [], 'Vy': [], 'Vxy': []}

    for dt in range(max_dt-1):
        # vx(t)vx(t+deltaT) + vy(t)vy(t+deltaT)
        tmpVx = allVx[dt:max_dt-1] * allVx[0:max_dt-1-dt]
        tmpVy = allVy[dt:max_dt-1] * allVy[0:max_dt-1-dt]
        tmpVxy = tmpVx + tmpVy

        # Moyenner sur tous les t possibles pour un deltaT
        data_corre['Vx'].append(tmpVx.mean())
        data_corre['Vy'].append(tmpVy.mean())
        data_corre['Vxy'].append(tmpVxy.mean())

    return pd.DataFrame(data_corre)
```

With `data_vit` containing 1000 points and `max_dt` set to 100, this code is roughly 500 times faster than the reference implementation on my desktop computer.

Note that it can still be improved by computing the means incrementally.